# Plotting histograms with R; y axis keeps changing to frequency from proportion/probability

Tags: r, histogram

I try to overlay two histograms in the same plane but the option Probability=TRUE (relative frequencies) in hist() is not effective with the code below. It is a problem because the two samples have very different sizes (length(cl1)=9 and length(cl2)=339) and, with this script, I cannot vizualize differences between both histograms because each shows frequencies. How can I overlap two histograms with the same bin width, showing relative frequencies?

```
c1<-hist(dataList[["cl1"]],xlim=range(minx,maxx),breaks=seq(minx,maxx,pasx),col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4),main=paste(paramlab,"Group",groupnum,"cl1",sep=" "),xlab="",probability=TRUE) 
c2<-hist(dataList[["cl2"]],xlim=range(minx,maxx),breaks=seq(minx,maxx,pasx),col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4),main=paste(paramlab,"Group",groupnum,"cl2",sep=" "),xlab="",probability=TRUE)
plot(c1, col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4), xlim=c(minx,maxx), main=paste(paramlab,"Group",groupnum,sep=" "),xlab="")# first histogram
plot(c2, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4), xlim=c(minx,maxx), add=T)
cl1Col <- rgb(1,0,0,1/4)
cl2Col <- rgb(0,0,1,1/4)
legend('topright',c('Cl1','Cl2'),
fill = c(cl1Col , cl2Col ), bty = 'n',
border = NA)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sample data would help

Comment: In the future, please dput() the relevant objects needed to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call plot on an object of class histogram (like c1), it calls the S3 method for the histogram.  Namely, `plot.histogram`.  You can see the code for this function if you type `graphics:::plot.histogram` and you can see its help under `?plot.histogram`.  The help file for that function states:

> freq   logical; if TRUE, the histogram graphic is to present a
>   representation of frequencies, i.e, `x$counts`; if FALSE, relative
>   frequencies (probabilities), i.e., x$density, are plotted. The default
>   is true for equidistant breaks and false otherwise.

So, when plot renders a histogram it doesn't use the previously specified `probability` or `freq` arguments, it tries to figure it out for itself.  The reason for this is obvious if you dig around inside `c1`, it contains all of the data necessarily for the plot, but does not specify how it should be rendered.

So, the solution is to reiterate the argument `freq=FALSE` when you run the plot functions.  Notably, `freq=FALSE` works whereas `probability=TRUE` does not because `plot.histogram` does not have a probability option.  So, your plot code will be:

```
plot(c1, col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4), xlim=c(minx,maxx), main=paste(paramlab,"Group",groupnum,sep=" "),xlab="",freq=FALSE)# first histogram
plot(c2, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/4), xlim=c(minx,maxx), add=T, freq=FALSE)
```

This all seems like a oversight/idiosyncratic decision (or lack thereof) on the part of the R devs.  To their credit it is appropriately documented and is not "unexpected behavior" (although I certainly didn't expect it).  I wonder where such oddness should be reported, if it should be reported at all.

Comment: @Lio:  That's great to hear.  Would you please mark the answer as accepted? (The checkmark).